# Horizontal UIStackView with different UILabels

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I'm adding UILabels into UIStackView programmatically. So I have labels with similar frames, but the length of the text isn't similar.
Looks like

```
[lb1           ]_[label2        ]_[label3longtext]
```

I need:

```
[lb1]__________[label2]__________[label3longtext]
```

Comment: You can set the distribution to `equalCentering`. Give it a try.

Comment: Don't work. Because UIStackView the size of all labels are equal. Size of label1 with short text is equal to label3 with long text. This way the count of whitespaces between label1 & label2 and label2&label3 is different.

Comment: @VRoman - is one of these the layout you want? https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaFNw.png

Comment: @DonMag : Wow, thanks. Will check out, why .proportionally won't work.